# Objective-C: conditionally call different properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties, conditional-statements

Say there's class that contains two different properties such as:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property id valueWhenNO;
@property id valueWhenYES;

@end
```

While using this class with a boolean value called 'state', I know I can get the property according to the its 'state' by:

```
MyClass *myClass;
id value = state ? myClass.valueWhenYES : myClass.valueWhenNO;
```

But I found that using a lot of conditional statement in a complex code can make the readability of it very hard. Since I intend to give no information about 'state' to 'MyClass', there cannot be additional boolean property in 'MyClass'.

Is there any way in Objective-C class that can be used to get property conditionally with a short line of code such like the following?

```
id value = myClass.valueByState;
```

Comment: You could make the properties methods than input your conditionals in the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Have 2 instances of a class with 1 property instead of 1 instance with 2 properties. Then, when the state changes you switch instance instead of having code everywhere to check the state.

Comment: Would be great to add that this can be easily achieved with id<protocol> or subclassing with base class for a set of objects with the same interface.

Comment: @Andy I was thinking simpler in just having one class that you instantiated with different values, but protocols is a fine approach too

Answer (score 0):

You could put the switching logic in a read only property..

-(id) appropriateObject{ return ((state)? self.valueWhenYes : self.valueWhenNo ); }